# File paths can't be found from shared library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an app wheere the user can view images attached to a sample, and then they need to be able to email the details of that sample (including image attachements) to stakeholders.

In my web.config of the web app, I have:

```
<add key="ImagesPath" value="~/Images" />
```

And this path seems to work perfectly for retrieving and displaying the images, which are stored in an images folder in the project.

However, when I try adding the image as attachments to an email (**from a shared library**) The app suddenly can't find the path with this error when calling

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(item));
```

**when debugging**

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Images\3000\1\1\3.png'.

**after publishing**

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\~\Images\9251\1\1\1.JPG'.

**What I tried**

1.

I tried calling this before creating the attachment

```
var appDomain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var basePath = appDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? appDomain.BaseDirectory;
var p = Path.Combine(basePath, item);
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(p));
```

But the app still can't find the files.

2. I tried calling

   ```
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item);

   message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(item));
   ```

before creating each attachment, but again theh images can't be found.

Can anyone please help me resolve this.

Comment: Did you try `message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item)));` ?

Comment: What is the value in `item`?

Comment: @Shyju I just tested your suggestion and it seems to have worked thank you! `item` is just a path to the file. If you want to add an answer I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you posted, you seems to call the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(item);` method, but not using the result of that to create the Attachment.

The `Server.MapPath` returns the physical location of the file. Use the result of the call to that method to add the attachment.

This should work.

```
var item = "3000/1/1/3.png";
var fileLocation = Path.Combine("images/",item);
var fullPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileLocation);
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fullPath));
```

Sometimes, I tend to do a file exist check before actually trying to access it.

```
if (File.Exists(fullPath ))
{
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fullPath));
}
```

If you are using it from an MVC controller, you may  use `Url.Content` along with `Server.MapPath`

```
var p = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/images/3000/1/1/3.png"));
```